# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.SaveAs2 COMException: Command failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, interop, office-interop

I have an ASP.NET MVC app which is generating a temporary docx file within application's folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\Data and later it converts to PDF and place it in the same folder where docx is.

App Pool is configured to run with a custom account.

Temporary docx file is generated correctly within application's folder but when I try to convert it to PDF and save it in the same folder where docx file is, I get a COMException saying command failed.

Once docx file is created in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\Data I convert it to PDF and place it in the same folder by performing below:

```
public void ConvertToPDF(string myDocFile)
{
    // myDocFile contains "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\MyApp\\Data\\mytempdocxfile.docx"
    Document myDoc = GetMyDoc(myDocFile);

    string myPdfFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(myDocFile), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myDocFile) + ".pdf");

    // myPdfFile now contains: "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\MyApp\\Data\\mytempdocxfile.pdf"
    myDoc.SaveAs2(myPdfFile, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF); // <--- HERE IT CRASHES: COMException command failed!!
    
    ...
}

public Document GetMyDoc(object docfile)
{
   // docFile contains "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\MyApp\\Data\\mytempdocxfile.docx"

   Application wApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
   Document myDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(ref docFile);
   
   return myDoc;
}
```

I have given full control permissions for the custom account specified for App Pool in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\Data.

I have tried to save the pdf file using a different name which does not match with docx file name and it does not work.

Finally I have tried to save the converted pdf file to a different location such as c:\temp and it works.

So, why pdf file is not being saved to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\Data ?

Comment: Doomed to fail, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

Comment: @LexLi It was working perfectly with another domain user account previously set in app pool but it suddenly stopped working after changing it by another custom user account.

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could try to use process monitor to find out the actually reason about why the custom account is working. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://improve.dk/solving-access-denied-errors-using-process-monitor/).

Comment: That never changes the fact that you are on an unsupported path.

Comment: @LexLi Furthermore if it is doomed to fail, why has it been working smoothly until today using the old user account? It stopped working once user account was changed.

Comment: The term “not supported” does allow it to work sometimes, but no complaint when it breaks.